# Ember.js handlebar precompilation via Gulp

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, gulp

I'm compiling my handlebar templates for ember via the [gulp-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-handlebars) plugin, which is working fine in browser, however once I introduce `{{outlet}}`s into the template structure the compilation runs fine, but the browser doesn't render as expected, it seems to have trouble with correctly resolving the outletSource. I've seen a couple of old SO questions which regard issues with HB compilation for ember, but they're a bit old, and wondering if anyone has any success with getting them it to work.

I'm fairly sure it's due to the compilation, if I move the templates into inline `<script>` tags then it works as expected

**Router configuration:**

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

Todos.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function () {  });
});

Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('todo');
  }
});

Todos.TodosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('todos');
  }
});
```

**Todos.hbs:**

```
<section id="main">
    {{outlet}}

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
</section>
```

**Todos/index.hbs:**

```
<!-- random html -->
```

**Demo:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61r6rru7/)

Comment: Please post your router configuration and the relevant bits of your templates.

Comment: Looks good-  I agree with you that it is probably a problem with your build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem in the build script was that I was using

```
.pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
```

And not

```
.pipe(wrap('Ember.Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for how to compile templates for ember here: https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/tree/master/examples/ember

I use the `gulp-ember-handlebars` plugin, but now it appears `gulp-handlebars` officially supports ember as well.

The main key seems to be using the specific `ember-handlebars` compiler:

```
.pipe(handlebars({
  handlebars: require('ember-handlebars')
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [gulp-ember-templates](https://github.com/swelham/gulp-ember-templates) plugin, it can output for browser, amd, cjs, and es6. yet it's a little buggy for AMD, though I have a workaround take a look at my [task](https://github.com/eguneys/gulp-ember-requirejs/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L67).